# Does the smallest prime factor of a Fibonacci number appear in the Fibonacci sequence?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers

I thought of a way to tackle the problem of knowing whether there are infinitely many Fibonacci primes or not and this question came to my mind: does the smallest prime factor of any Fibonacci number necessarily appear in the Fibonacci sequence?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The 19th Fibonacci number is 4181 = 37*113, but 37 is not a Fibonacci number.

Comment: And neither is 113.  No prime factor of a Fibonacci number need be a Fibonnaci number itself.